# How can I extend a JS Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this custom component

```
(function ($) {   
    $.fn.stuff = function (options) {
        var myStuff = this;

        myStuff.render_item = function () {
           // Do something
            return "default result";
        };

        myStuff.test = function () {
            myStuff.render_item;
        };

        return myStuff;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

I want to "extend" this component and re-declare the "render_item" fonction without editing the file directly since it's from a library.

How can I achieve this ?
Thank you.

Comment: A typical monkey-patch will do. There's no way to gain access to the code that creates the function, so you'll have to just replace it after it has been created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can monkey-patch it like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.old_stuff = $.fn.stuff;
  $.fn.stuff = function(options) {
    var myStuff = $(this).old_stuff(options);
    myStuff.old_render_item = myStuff.render_item;
    myStuff.render_item = function() {
      // do something
      myStuff.old_render_item();
      // do something else
    };

    return myStuff;
  };

}(jQuery));
```